# Vue-Multiselect is empty - Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I've been implementing the latest Vue-Multiselect and have it rendering in the page ok. For some reason the `v-model` value doesn't seem to be taking effect as it's staying empty.

```
import { Multiselect } from 'vue-multiselect'

var MultiSelect = Vue.extend({
components: { Multiselect },
template: '<div><multiselect :options="options" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :clear-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" placeholder="Please select..." label="name" track-by="name"></multiselect></div>',
    data: function() {
        return {
            value: [],
            options: []
        };
    }
});

Vue.component('multi-select', MultiSelect);
```

I'm setting all the options as per an example:

```
options: [
                {
                    language: 'Javascript',
                    libs: [
                        { name: 'Vue.js', category: 'Front-end' },
                        { name: 'Adonis', category: 'Backend' }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    language: 'Ruby',
                    libs: [
                        { name: 'Rails', category: 'Backend' },
                        { name: 'Sinatra', category: 'Backend' }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    language: 'Other',
                    libs: [
                        { name: 'Laravel', category: 'Backend' },
                        { name: 'Phoenix', category: 'Backend' }
                    ]
                }
            ],
```

This is the code in the blade:

```
    <multi-select v-model="updateTutorInstrumentsForm.options" group-values="libs" group-label="language"></multi-select>

    <pre>@{{ updateTutorInstrumentsForm.options }}</pre>
```

[image: Output]

A bit confused to say the least!

Comment: My guess would have to do with the fact you're encapsulating the multi-select so v-model doesn't have anything to attach to. have you tried moving value from data to props? it also doesn't look like you're usign the value parameter anywhere inside the component.

Comment: Thanks @JustinMacArthur, I've resolved it thanks to your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this.

Thanks to Justin's comment about encapsulating the multi-select, I decided to break it out and did the following:

```
import { Multiselect } from 'vue-multiselect'

var CustomSelect = Vue.extend({
components: { Multiselect },
template: '<div><multiselect :multiple="true" :selected="selected" :options="options" group-values="instruments" group-label="name" track-by="name" label="name"></multiselect></div>',

created() {
    this.getInstruments();
},

data: function() {
    return {
        selected: null,
        options: []
    };
},

methods: {
    getInstruments() {
        this.$http.get('/get/instruments')
            .then(response => {
                this.instruments = response.data;
                this.updateInstruments();
            });
    },

    updateInstruments() {
        this.options = this.instruments;
    },
}
});

Vue.component('customselect', CustomSelect);
```

Then in the blade template, simply: `<customselect></customselect>`